# Ubuntu: As of 2013 how to keep vpnc connection alive?

Tags: ubuntu, cisco, vpn

I am using ubuntu 10.14 and there is a need to connect to a `cisco vpn`. after several attempts on installing `cisco vpn client` from [here](http://www.lamnk.com/blog/vpn/how-to-install-cisco-vpn-client-on-ubuntu-jaunty-jackalope-and-karmic-koala-64-bit/) which succeeded installing finally but i couldn't connect. So i fall to `vpnc(0.5.3)` from ubuntu repository which connects me right away just that connection wouldn't stay alive.A fter other research online i had to add :

```
DPD idle timeout (our side) 0
NAT Traversal Mode cisco-udp
```

It still doesn't stay alive so my question is how do you guys do nowadays, is there any other alternative?

Thanks for reading this

Comment: I have the same issue in 13.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to pull something out using `telnet` ,`crontab` on top of ubuntu stock vpnc. I put some notes on my blog [mycodingpains.com](http://www.mycodingpains.com/lstable-vpnc-connection-ubuntu-2-2/) . I hope it will be useful to you.

all the best